# Problems with caching in axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, axios, fetch

I am building an application in which I make an api call using axios to list data, however I am having problems with caching.

What happens is that the requests always have the same response, and when trying to pass the header `"Cache-Control": "no-store"` the request is error.

I made the same request using the fetch method passing the  option `cache: "no-store"` and it worked correctly.

Has anyone experienced anything similar or have any idea what it might be?

Axios:

```
 const { data } = await api.get<GetPostsResponse>(
  "https://dogsapi.origamid.dev/json/api/photo",
  {
    params: {
      _page: page,
      _total: itemsPerPage,
      _user: userId
    },
    headers: {
      "Cache-Control": "no-store"
    }
  }
);
```

Fetch:

```
const data = await fetch(
  `https://dogsapi.origamid.dev/json/api/photo/?_page=${page}&_total=${itemsPerPage}&_user=${userId}`,
  {
    cache: "no-store",
    method: "GET"
  }
).then(async (response) => await response.json());
```

If you want to have a look at the repository: https://github.com/CaioVinicius7/dogs

The file that contains the request is `src/services/post.ts` (I left without the cache-control header for now, so if you run the project you will see the problem) and this service of the request is called in the file `src/components/Feed.tsx`